# Unity Forward Rotation One Direction

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation

I am still new to Unity and programming in general. I have tried looking through the forums for this problem but I feel the need to ask anyways since I get confused reading and trying to tell if the person's problem is exactly the same as mine. I have this code that when you press w which is forward it forces the the player to go forward in one direction regardless of where the player is facing. I know this kind of thing has been talked about before but I want to know exactly where I am messing up. Maybe something with using Space.World instead of Self or combining vectors and transform. Any help would be appreciated.

Screenshot of the code:
[image: code]

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out what you're aiming for. Is this a top down game, or a first person game? Do you want movement to follow the character's rotation, or do you want the character's rotation to follow the movement?

Comment: Sorry, I am aiming for a 3rd person platformer with the camera following the player. I guess I would want the character to prioritize forward motion. The problem is when I turn it turns the character 90 degrees but when I press w or the up arrow to move forward the character will move forward but first it will rotate -90 degrees back to its original position.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please copy and paste the code into the question rather than using a screenshot